# Is it possible to allow access to a doc if the user is a member of a parent document, or parent's parent, recursively?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here's my data structure:

```
folders(collection): {
    folderA: {
        members: { user123: { role: "author" } }
        folders(collection): {
            folderB: {
                parent(reference): /folders/folderA
                members: { userABC: { role: "author" } }
                folders(collection): {
                    folderC: {
                        parent(reference): /folders/folderA/folders/folderB
                        fieldA: { content: 'x' }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
users: {
    user123 :{
        name: John
    }
    userABC :{
        name: Bob
    }
}
```

My goal is to allow access to a document by a user that is a member of any parent above the currently requested document. The hope is to allow access to **fieldA** by both **user123** (John) and **userABC** (Bob) without writing rules specific to **folderA, folderB, and folderC**. The idea is that potentially there could be folders at least 20 deep.

Even though I know rule functions are limited, this is how I wish I could write the rules for this case:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{path=**} {
        allow get: if resource.data.members[request.auth.uid].role == 'author';
        allow get: if isParentAuthor(resource);

        function isParentAuthor(resource){
            if(exists(resource.data.parent) {
                if( get(resource.data.parent.path).data.members[request.auth.uid].role == 'author' ) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return isParentAuthor( get(resource.data.parent.path) );
                }
            } else {
                return false
            }   
        }

    }
}
```

Right now I have many levels deep of access to the folders hard coded into my rules. But it would be great to be able to do this recursively. Is that possible? I know that this would create a situation where there could potentially be quite a few document requests, but I think I'm generally okay with that. But maybe there's a more Firebase-y way to pull this off with fewer requests?

Comment: I would personally flatten how you're storing folders in firebase. Just have a top-level collection of folders. Not sure why they need to be stored in nested format like this, I think that just makes security more difficult and confusing to implement. Then each folder can have additional _array_ fields that keep track of who has read access, write access, etc., and you can use an `array_contains` operator to determine permissions.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I can definitely understand flattening. But in this case, even if the database is flat, permissions are still based on a hierarchy of parents, which is the design requirement in this case. That still makes the security rules challenge the same (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: I just don't see how that's going to be feasible unless you duplicate some of the permissions in your firebase schema at each level. I don't think it was intended for arbitrarily deep nested collections with security rules that would apply at each level recursively.

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations with security rules that make it impossible to do what you're saying here.

First, there is a limit of 10 document gets per rule invocation.  This is a hard limit.

Second, there is no recursion allowed.  The rule will immediately fail if a function calls itself.

As suggested in comments, flatten your collections.  Put a field in the document to indicate where it's logically nested compared to other documents.  Having large collections is not a big deal with Cloud Firestore.  You will be able to filter as much as you need with queries.